# Android: Toast in tabbed application & Next page onclick in tabbed application

Tags: android, toast, android-tabbed-activity

I am trying to create a Toast from inside my fragment. I have been searching for hours on the internet and all I come across doesn't seem to work.

```
information.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "This information will not be published in the world wide web, but will be saved on your own device instead", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                }
            });
```

'**getActivity**' is red. On hover it says: "**cannot resolve method 'getActivity()**'".
If I remove the getActivity, and only use **getBaseContext()** or **getApplicationContext()**, it says that the **non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context**. Can anyone teach me how to create this specific Toast?

I used the standard gallery tabbed application from Android Studio.
Here is my code (you will find it at the very bottom):

```
public class ApplicationFragments extends AppCompatActivity {
        private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
        private ViewPager mViewPager;

        //get widgets voor alle functies
        private static View rootView;

        //variable
        private static int section;
        //fragment1
        static ImageButton information;
        static int addOneSex;
        static int addOneWeight;
        static int addOneAge;
        static ImageView plusSex;
        static ImageView plusWeight;
        static ImageView plusAge;
        static TextView sex;
        static TextView weight;
        static TextView age;

        //fragment2
        static int addOneHour;
        static int addOneBeer;
        static int addOneWine;
        static int addOneShot;
        static ImageView plusBeers;
        static ImageView plusWines;
        static ImageView plusShots;
        static TextView plusHours;
        static TextView amountOfHours;
        static TextView amountOfBeers;
        static TextView amountOfWines;
        static TextView amountOfShots;

        //fragment3

        //all fragments
        static Button btnNext;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //verander animatie
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.fade_out);

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);

            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
            // primary sections of the activity.
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        }

        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
            private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

            public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
                PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            //bij het creëren van een tab
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_information, container, false);

                //set xml
                section = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
                if (section == 1) {
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_information, container, false);
                    GenerateFragment1();
                }
                if (section == 2) {
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drinks, container, false);
                    GenerateFragment2();
                }
                if (section == 3) {
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculate, container, false);
                    GenerateFragment3();
                }
                return rootView;
            }
        }

        //geef de juiste pagina terug
        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                //hoeveelheid pagina's
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return "SECTION 1";
                    case 1:
                        return "SECTION 2";
                    case 2:
                        return "SECTION 3";
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        //fragment 1
        public static void GenerateFragment1(){
            information = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnInfo);
            sex = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etSex);
            weight = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etWeight);
            age = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etAge);
            plusSex = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSex);
            plusWeight = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnWeight);
            plusAge = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAge);
            btnNext = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

            plusSex.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    addOneSex = Integer.parseInt(sex.getText().toString());
                    addOneSex++;
                    sex.setText(Integer.toString(addOneSex));
                }
            });

            plusWeight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    addOneWeight = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
                    addOneWeight++;
                    weight.setText(Integer.toString(addOneWeight));
                }
            });

            plusAge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    addOneAge = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
                    addOneAge++;
                    age.setText(Integer.toString(addOneAge));
                }
            });


            information.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "This information will not be published in the world wide web, but will be saved on your own device instead", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                }
            });

            btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //to the next fragment
                }
            });
        }
```

Also, I am wondering how I can make the app go to the next page on a buttonclick (btnNext).

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: may I know what is the intention behind making all your variables static?? I mean why are even your buttons and image view is static??

Comment: Because if I don't put static in front of it, it says: 'non-static field ... cannot be referenced from a static context'. I'm fairly new so if there's a better way, shoot!

Comment: Well making even drawable resources static would rip off your phone memory like hell..and would result in out of memory errors and results in app crash... May i know what exactly you are trying to do.. Whats your approach ?? do you have single activity and rest are fragments?? or  you have multiple activities??

Comment: This is one activity, three XML's, 3 different tabs

Comment: based on the section numbers I inflate a different XML and get the widgets on that XML and put onclicklisteners

Comment: try getcontext() instead of getActivity.getbasecontext()

Comment: cannot resolve method..

Comment: I don't think its a good approach to make everything static, and having protected class and static class without having knowledge of what those keywords are meant for... I would suggest you to get basic knowledge on them before jumping to android...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a list of fragments stored in the activity somewhere, or a fragment manager? If so, you can just get the next fragment from the list and switch it out with the fragment manager. Regarding the toast getActivity() problem: if I understand correctly, ApplicationFragments is your main activity? If so, why not call `ApplicationFragments.this` instead of getActivity()?

Comment: cannot be referenced from a static context. It's not really my mainactivity, since I have a menu before this tabbed activity

Comment: ApplicationFragments.this you mean? Also, why not change almost all fields to private and non static? It would get rid of a lot of potential problems.

Comment: Also, do you mind linking the tutorial/guide which you followed?

Comment: I used the standard tabbed application from Android Studio, I didn't follow any tutorial. When I remove static it will say 'non-static method ... cannot be referenced from a static context'.

Comment: Ok, I see. If you remove static from the variables, which method(s) say "cannot be referenced from a static context" ?

Comment: All of them basicly, I cannot use any of the variables, so I cannot use rootView.findViewById(). --> can't use anything

Comment: Would you mind listing some? For example, does getPageTitle ()  give an error?

Comment: No that works perfectly fine, it's only my own variables (textviews, buttons, ...) and as soon as I put static in front, they all work perfectly fine. for example: If I remove static at 'information', information will show red at the bottom and say that same cannot be referenced from static context error

Comment: That's most likely because it's in the body of GenerateFragment1(), which is static. Do you have any particular reason for making that static? Also, I'm confused as to what that method actually does.

Comment: No, no reason at all. I'm new so i'm happy if I do something and it works.
I created the method to get all the current textviews, buttons, ... set onclicklisteners, ... on that XML file. 

When it opens the second tab, it will GenerateFragment2(), where the method will get all the current textviews etc aswell.

Comment: Ahh the reason why I made it static is because if I remove 'static' in the function, it will say at GenerateFragment1(): non-static method GenerateFragment1() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Ok, I see. By "standard tabbed application" are you looking to create something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/feMQ1.png ?

Comment: Yes. Instead of the tabs ontop I would like to swipe and I need to access all the data entered on these tabs

Comment: but my current app is working fine, apart from the toast honestly

Comment: The tabs are on top, so you can either click on them to transfer pages, or swipe to transfer tabs. But, anyways, I understand now. I've implemented basically what you're looking for in my app, by following this tutorial: https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-tabs-with-fragments-and-viewpager-tutorial/ . The GetFragment1() method that you've implemented is not the correct way to go about implementing tabs.

Comment: The structure that you have now makes your app very inflexible and hard to change. If you implement the structure presented in the tutorial, then everything should work out. You can do all of the toast business in the separate fragment classes.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I will definitly try out this tutorial

Comment: Np! And if you need further help, it'd be better to move to chat. Also, two tips for the future: don't make things static unless you need to. And for this particular app: if you find that you need to transfer data from your main activity to your Fragments (tabs), then look into what LocalBroadcastManager is. It will save you much, much heartache.

Comment: Tutorial seems to be incomplete. The IDs: 'pager' and 'tab_layout' do not exist :/ Read the comments and those people have that aswell. BUT, i think I found a promissing tutorial right here: http://haidermushtaq.com/tutorial-for-creating-android-swiping-application-using-tabbed-activity-on-android-studio/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120320/discussion-between-miki-p-and-meindert-stijfhals).